# server-to-server multicast messaging with Google Cloud PubSub?

Tags: rabbitmq, google-cloud-messaging, message-queue, multicast, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cluster of backend servers on GCP, and they need to send messages to each other.  All the servers need to receive every message, but I can tolerate a low error rate.  I can deal with receiving the message more than once on a given server.  Packet ordering doesn't matter.

I don't need much of a persistence layer.  A message becomes stale within a couple of seconds after sending it.

I wired up Google Cloud PubSub and pretty quickly realized that for a given subscription, you can have any number of subscribers but only one of them is guaranteed to get the message.  I considered making the subscribers all fail to ack it, but that seems like a gross hack that probably won't work well.

My server cluster is sized dynamically by an autoscaler.  It spins up VM instances as needed, with dynamic hostnames and IP addresses.  There is no convenient way to map the dynamic hosts to static subscriptions, but it feels like that's my only real option:  Create more subscriptions than my max server pool size, and then use some sort of paxos system (runtime config, zookeeper, whatever) to allocate servers to subscriptions.

I'm starting to feel that even though my use case feels really simple ("Every server can multicast a message to every other server in my group"), it may not be a good fit for Cloud PubSub.

Should I be using GCM/FCM?  Or some other technology?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Pub/Sub may or may not be a fit for you, depending on the size of your server cluster. Failing to ack the messages certainly won't work because you can't be sure each instance will get the message; it could just be redelivered to the same instance over and over again.

You could use multiple subscriptions and have each instance create a new subscription when it starts up. This only works if you don't plan to scale beyond 10,000 instances in your cluster, as that is the maximum number of subscriptions per topic allowed. The difficulty here is in cleaning up subscriptions for instances that go down. Ones that cleanly shut down could probably delete their own subscriptions, but there will always be some that don't get cleaned up. You'd need some kind of external process that can determine if the instance for each subscription is still up and running and if not, delete the subscription. You could use [GCE shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript)s to catch this most of the time, though there will still be edge cases where deletes would have to be done manually.